# Xampp in chrome works fine but not open in mozilla browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, xampp, mozilla, localserver

I have recently install **Xampp PHP 5.2.0** . After setup the settings,

I found it well working in Chrome but in Mozilla, it is not working.

Display "It works!".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please say the error you see ??????

Comment: Are you using any VPN or Proxy software?

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A . There is no error displaying.

Comment: @MohammadAliTaqvazadeh no I am not using VPN or Proxy software.

Answer (score 0):

In Mozilla Firefox, check if you have proxy on. Go to Options, then under Network Settings, click "Settings" then make sure that "No Proxy" is enabled. (see screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: @miken32, In Mozilla for local server not displaying directories/listing. What can i do ?